# How to read a value from c# library (.dll) inside my (.wxs) installer file

Tags: c#, dll, wix, installation, embedded-resource

I have a .net solution , the main project is windows forms application. I made a **wix installer** project that packaged my project .

I have a Resources.dll that contains some images , version number and the name of the application.

what i need is to read a the value of the version number , and an image from this resource inside my .wxs file. is it Possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can send your values from command prompt.

From your WinForm :

```
 using (var p = new Process())
                {
                    var info = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                        FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",
                        Arguments = string.Format("/c msiexec /i \"{0}\\{6}.msi\" PATHNAME=\"{0}\" SSLCERTPATH=\"{1}\"" +
                        " MSINEWINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=\":{2}\" USERPATH={3} ENVIRONMENTPATH={4} SSLCERTPASS=\"{5}\" /L*v \"{0}\\{6}Log.txt\""
                        , XmlSettings.EnvironmentFolderPath, FindCertificates.SslCertPath, environment, XmlSettings.IisUserFolderPath,
                        XmlSettings.EnvironmentFolderPath, FindCertificates.SslCertPass, msiName),
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        CreateNoWindow = true
                    };
                    p.Start();
                    p.WaitForExit();
                }
```

And in the wxs :

```
  <Property Id="SITEPHYSPATH"  Hidden="yes"/>
    <Property Id="USERPATH"  Hidden="yes"/>
    <Property Id="ENVIRONMENTPATH"  Hidden="yes"/>
    <Property Id="PATHNAME" Hidden="yes" />
```

Then last in the custom action you can do anything with your values , but first set them :

```
var userpath = session["USERPATH"];
```